# Delphi: how to access an object's base class methods from an interface type variable

Tags: delphi, interface

...or vice versa. Let's suppose two classes on which I have no control, both inherit from the same base class:

```pascal
TDataSet1 = class(TDataSet)
...
end;

TDataSet2 = class(TDataSet)
...
end;
```

I have an interface declaration like this:

```pascal
IMyDataSet = interface
  procedure MyProc;
end;
```

Then I have two classes that inherit from the previous ones and that implement my interface:

```pascal
TMyDataSet1 = class(TDataSet1, IMyDataSet)
  procedure MyProc;
end;

TMyDataSet2 = class(TDataSet2, IMyDataSet)
  procedure MyProc;
end;
```

Now my problem is: i have a bunch of procedures and functions which must accept as parameter an object which can be an instance of both my classes.
I don't need to access properties or methods specific to my two classes or to the ancestor ones, only those from the base class `TDataSet` **and** those declared in the interface `IMyDataSet`.

If I declare a procedure like this:

```pascal
procedure Foo(ADataSet: TDataSet);
```

I can only call methods from `TDataSet` class.

If instead I declare the procedure in this way:

```pascal
procedure Foo(ADataSet: IMyDataSet);
```

I can see only methods that belong to that interface.

Is there a way so that I can see **both `TDataSet` and `IMyDataSet` methods** on the reference I pass to the procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare parameter as interface and then typecast it to object reference inside method. (This kind of typecasting works in Delphi 2010 and newer)

```
procedure Foo(ADataSet: IMyDataSet);
var
  LDataSet: TDataSet;
begin
  LDataSet := TDataSet(ADataSet);
  ... 
end;
```

Note: If `IMyDataSet` interface is not implemented on `TDataSet` class above typecast will fail without raising exception and return `nil`.

You can also use `as` operator to typecast, but in that case failure raises exception.

```
LDataSet := ADataSet as TDataSet;
```

---

Another option is to pass parameter as object instance and then retrieve interface from object. In that case your interface must have GUID.

```
IMyDataSet = interface
  ['{XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'] // replace with actual GUID
  procedure MyProc;
end;

procedure Foo(ADataSet: TDataSet);
var
  LDataSet: IMyDataSet;
begin
  if Supports(ADataSet, IMyDataSet, LDataSet) then
    begin
      ... 
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I think your first answer may not apply to my case, TDataSet definitely doesn't implement IMyDataSet (my example is quite close to the real conditions, TDataSet is exactly the native TDataSet class from Delphi). Actually both my classes implement IMyDataSet, but will this be enough for the typecast to work?
Second answer seems ok... I have literally hundreds of procedures and functions to which I have to pass these objects, so maybe I can make a function which does this Supports thing and return the interface reference, will it work?

Comment: If I understood you correctly your TDataSet1 that implements IMyDataset inherits from TDataSet (that is what you wrote) and first answer will work. If that is not the case, then the second answer will not work either.

Comment: It's actually TMyDataSet1 (and 2) that implements IMyDataSet, while on TDataSet1 I have no control. Anyway, if I understood you correctly, if my param is of type IMyDataSet and I pass an instance of TMyDataSet1 (that implements the interface), the cast will work, right? BTW, the second way seems more usable to me, I'll write a little function that returns IMyDataSet and use it only when I need to call methods from that interface, leaving the rest of the code that uses methods from TDataSet intact (I'm doing an "upgrade" on old code).

Comment: As long as all classes have TDataSet as ancestor it does not matter at which point (class) you actually implement interface. You can chose both approaches, depending on which one suits you more.